# How to set afterEach handler in vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following script:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    // purposely left blank
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: SampleComponent
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to add an `afterEach` handler to the router so that I can close any open menus when a router link is taken.

I tried to add it to the constructor but it is not a constructor argument.

I also tried:

```
Router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  // ...
})
```

But I get an error:

> afterEach is not a function

How do I appropriately add an `afterEach` callback with this setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `afterEach` handler on a `Router` instance (the object returned via `new Router()`).

You can set a reference to your instance, and add the `afterEach` handler to it before it's exported:

```
const router = new Router({
  scrollBehavior (to, from, savedPosition) {
    // purposely left blank
  },
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      component: SampleComponent
    }
  ]
});

router.afterEach((to, from) => {
  // ...
});

export default router
```

Comment: Is "Router" in the code sample not the instance? It too is defined as
"import Router from 'vue-router'"

Comment: `Router` is the class, not the instance. I updated my answer to be clearer.

Comment: how to do this in vue 3?